# deploy flutter app from different machine that the published version

Tags: console, playback, android-app-signing

i am new to flutter development and i am stuck on the issue for almost a month now.

i have a project in flutter that as initially developed on another machine and made live on google play.

now i want to update the app from another machine but i receieve the error

"Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your app bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:"

SHA1: XX:XX:......
but the certificate used to sign the app bundle that you uploaded has fingerprint:
SHA1: YY:YY:YY:........

changing the signing key is not an option as my app is live with same key on Apple play and is using third party APIs.

i have the .jks file from previous machine and i have generated a new jks for my new machine too. but completely lost on where to place jks from previous machine into my machine to ensure my app is signed using existing key stores.

any help/workaround will be highly appreciated.

i tried copying the keystore in C:\users\username\keystore_new.jks